# Excel error 400 with ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert

Tags: excel, vba

I run into the vague "400" error with a trivial visual basic script in excel. I commented out everything, just leaving the single line in my method:
**ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert**

Here the "complete" (stripped) method (which is keybound to ctrl+shift+n):

```
Sub NewUserStory()
'
' NewUserStory Macro
' Creates a new empty user story with pasted formulas for remaining work, and cumulative planning information 
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+N
'
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert ' Insert a new row above selected row

End Sub
```

If I have any cell selected, and I press the macro, the debugger stops on my breakpoint. When I step into the method, I immediately get the popup with error "400". I am 100% sure that there is no other method that is executed.

I've been google-ing this for the last 2 hours, but nothing that solved the problem. Sorry for the lame question, but I need the bloody macro for my work :).

Many thanks in advance!

PS: If anybody can provide an alternative for ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert, I am all ears too of course!

Comment: Works for me (unless there's any content on the last row of the sheet...) Did you mean to tag with VBA (not VB.net)?

Comment: Tim, you are my personal hero! I added my collections for comboboxes at the bottom of my sheet instead of on another tab (had to move from office 2010 to 2007). Bulls eye! Thank you so much! Could you be so kind to post this as answer then I can give you the credits and maybe somebody else who is pulling is hair out can read your solution too. Thanks again!! Cheers, Bas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly you have content in the last row of the sheet you're trying to insert the row into?

That would cause an error.

Comment: +1 Worked for me, I had to delete the row I was trying to insert into to clear it out to make it work; couldn't _see_ any content in the row but could have been a rogue space character...